# Solving for a general form of a kernel from two dfiferential equation based conditions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

(Problem is encountered in my research on PDE Backstepping Control) Let us have some kernel function k(x, y) and it depends on some known function $\theta(x)$. How can we solve the following for the general form of k(x, y) given we have the conditions

$k(x, 0) = \theta(x) - \int_0^x k(x, y)\theta(y) dy$

$k_y(x, y) + k_x(x, y) = 0$
where $k_y$ denotes the partial derivative on y of k(x, y).

I know that solutions of the 2nd equation are in the form k(x-y), but I'm not sure how I can plug that into the first equation to get a general form of k(x, y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out, the second equation implies $k(x,y) = k(x-y)$; in consequence, the first relation becomes
$$
k(t) = \theta(t) - \int_0^tk(t-\tau)\theta(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau
$$
The last term is a **truncated** convolution product, which can be handled with the help of Laplace transform by mapping it to a standard product. One gets :
$$
\hat{k}(s) = \hat{\theta}(s) - \hat{k}(s)\hat{\theta}(s) \verb+  +\Rightarrow\verb+  + \hat{k}(s) = \frac{\hat{\theta}(s)}{1+\hat{\theta}(s)}
$$
And after that there's nothing for it but to take inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: @LutzLehmann OP wants $k$ given $\theta$. Thank you for the comment nonetheless, it enabled me to spot the wrong sign in the final answer.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful as I did not see the laplace transform component.